# Match variable value with text file row wise

Tags: php, file

I want to match variable value with text file rows, for example

```
$brands = 'Applica';
```

and text file content like -

```
'applica' = 'Applica','Black and Decker','George Foreman'
'black and decker' = 'Black and Decker','Applica'
'amana' = 'Amana','Whirlpool','Roper','Maytag','Kenmore','Kitchenaid','Jennair'
'bosch' = 'Bosch','Thermador'
```

As there are four rows in text file.

and first word of each row is brand which is compatible with their equal to brands.

like `applica` is compatible with 'Applica' and 'Black and Decker' and 'George Foreman'

I want to match variable `$brands` with word `applica` and if it matches then store their equal to value like `'Applica','Black and Decker','George Foreman'` in new variable.

Please provide some guidance.

Thanks.

Update -

```
<?php 
$brands  = "brands.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($brands);
$brandsfields = explode(',', $contents);
$csvbrand = 'applica';

foreach($brandsfields as $brand) {
        $newname = substr($brand,1,-1);
    echo $newname . "\t";
    }

?>
```

Comment: If your question is not about `mysql`, you should remove `mysql` tag.

Comment: I thought it would need mysql. because I am fetching brands name from mysql db and match with textfile rows.

Comment: @Steve Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/'" . $csvbrand ."' = (.*)/", $contents, $output_array);

$names = explode(",", str_replace("'", "", $output_array[1][0]));

 Var_dump($names); // results in ->
 //Applica
 //Black and Decker
 //George Foreman
```

Comment: @Steve as clear as mud. What is in brands.txt and how is it formatted? What do you want me to search in? Why is $csvbrand unused in the rest of the code, and what is it supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry for my crappy code. But Sofiene Answer solve my problem. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: @Steve I updated with what I believe you meant. The code you accepted is much longer and has unnessecary steps.

Comment: Answer with so much easy steps.. Perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
    $matches = explode("\n", "'applica' = 'Applica','Black and Decker','George Foreman'\n'black and decker' = 'Black and Decker','Applica'\n'amana' = 'Amana','Whirlpool','Roper','Maytag','Kenmore','Kitchenaid','Jennair'\n'bosch' = 'Bosch','Thermador'");
    $brand = "applica";
    $equalValues = [];
    foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
        $keyMatch = str_replace("'", "", trim(explode('=', $value)[0]));
        $valuesMatch = explode('=', $value)[1];
        $escapedDelimiter = preg_quote("'", '/');
        preg_match_all('/' . "'" . '(.*?)' . "'" . '/s', $valuesMatch, $matches);
        if ($brand == $keyMatch) {
            $equalValues = $matches[1];
        }
    }

    var_dump($equalValues);
```

if brand is equal to applica $equalvalues shoud be equal to :

```
array(3) {
   [0]=>
      string(7) "Applica"
   [1]=>
      string(16) "Black and Decker"
   [2]=>
      string(14) "George Foreman"
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code. I just dont want to copy and paste you code. I also want to learn. As I am using your code and assigning csv file column value to $brand variable like `$brand = trim(data[0]);` I am getting `Parse syntax error unexpected [] ` at `$equalValues = [];` that `[]` are unnecessary. Can you please check this and let me know what does it means in empty square brackets.

Comment: Hey, my english is not really good, i hope you will understand :),
the $equalValues is here to return an empty array if the brand does not match any value, the error come from the line above when you  assign your csv value into the variable brand.
did your forgot the $ in trim(data[0]); ?